# Devtools window in Electron app disappears suddenly when importing resize-img

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building my first Electron app guided by the Traversy Media video on youtube called "Create a Desktop App With JavaScript & Electron". Using VScode on Windows 10.

Everything works as expected till my main.js looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");
const fs = require("fs");


const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = require("electron");

const isMac = process.platform === "darwin";
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

//Create main window
function createMainWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        title: "Image resizer",
        height: 600,
        width: isDev ? 1000 : 500,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });

    //open dev tools if in dev environment
    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./renderer/index.html"));;

}

//Create about window
function createAboutWindow() {
    const aboutWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        title: "About Image resizer",
        height: 300,
        width: 300
    });

    aboutWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./renderer/about.html"));;

}

//App is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createMainWindow();

    //Implement menu
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createMainWindow();
        };
    })

});

//Menus
const menu = [
    ...(isMac ? [{
        label: app.name,
        submenu: {
            label: "About",
            click: createAboutWindow
        }
    }] : []),
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [{
            label: "Exit",
            click: () => app.quit(),
            accelerator: "Ctrl+W"
        }],
    },
    ...(!isMac ? [{
        label: "Help",
        submenu: [{
            label: "About",
            click: createAboutWindow
        }]
    }] : [])
];

//Respond to ipcRenderer resize
ipcMain.on("image:resize", (e, options) => {
    options.dest = path.join(os.homedir(), 'imageresizer');
    resizeImage(options);
})

//Resize the image
async function resizeImage({ imgPath, width, height, dest }) {
    try {
        const image = await resizeImg(fs.readFileSync(imgPath), {
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
        fs.writeFileSync(dest, image);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (!isMac) {
        app.quit();
    }
})
```

The app has an open devtools window created by line 25-27 and line 9.
The next step is to import  the resize-img module with the line

```
const resizeImg=require("resize-img")
```

But then my devtools window disappears, while the width of the app window stays 1000 pixels, meaning that isDev is still true.

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "image-resizer-electron",
    "productName": "Image resizer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "App to resize image",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "author": "dfsadfsadf",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "resize-img": "^2.0.0",
        "toastify-js": "^1.12.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^26.1.0"
    }
}
```

Also if I load the code from github (bradtraversy/image-resizer-electron) I get the same proble, so it is not a typo that is the cause.

Anyone any idea what is happening?

---

Meanwhile I stripped as much as possible from the code to get a minimum reproducable example. My main.js then looks like this (preload.js and renderer.js are now empty):

```
const path = require("path");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const resizeImg = require("resize-img");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

//Create main window
function createMainWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        title: "Image resizer",
        height: 600,
        width: isDev ? 1000 : 500,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });

    //open dev tools if in dev environment
    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./renderer/index.html"));;

}

//App is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createMainWindow();

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createMainWindow();
        };
    })

});


app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    app.quit();
})
```

This code generates an app that is 1000 pixels wide, but does not show the devtools.

If I remove line 3 (*const resizeImg = require("resize-img");*) then devtools is shown again.